# Add and Subtract Button in For Loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I´m trying to automaticly create an input with two buttons. One button for adding 1 and the other for subtrcting 1 to the value of the input.

With my code I can create those elements but when I click any subtract button it´s only subtracting 1 from the first input. Same with the add buttons.

Now I´m stuck because I don´t know how to change the code to connect e.g. the third created subtract button to the third created input.

I hope someone can help me out here.

Thank you

My Code:

````
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayinput.length; i++){
    
//Number Input Field
        var myParent3 = NumberContainer;
        var numberfield = document.createElement("input");
        numberfield.setAttribute('class','numberfield');
        numberfield.setAttribute('id','number');
        numberfield.setAttribute('value','0');      
        myParent3.appendChild(numberfield);
        
        
        
//Buttons to add and subtract
        var myParent4 = SubtractContainer;
        var subtractButton = document.createElement("button");
        subtractButton.setAttribute('class','subtractButton');
        subtractButton.textContent = "-";
        subtractButton.setAttribute('onclick','subtract()');
        myParent4.appendChild(subtractButton);
    
    
        var myParent5 = AddContainer;
        var addButton = document.createElement("button");
        addButton.setAttribute('class','addButton');
        addButton.textContent = "+";
        addButton.setAttribute('onclick','add()');
        myParent5.appendChild(addButton);   

    };
    
    function add(){
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);
        value++;
        document.getElementById('number').value = value;
    };
    function subtrahieren(){

        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);
        value--;
        document.getElementById('number').value = value;
    };
    ```
````

Comment: at first glance it looks like the problem here is that you give all your number input fields the id "number".  an id can only be given once. you would have to give them all an individual id for that to work. you could then pass that individual id as argument in the add and substract functions. not the cleanest solution but i don't think that's the point here.

Comment: I agree with @BlakkM9, your buttons should have unique Ids. Also JS does not like actual numbers as Ids, so avoid that. Each time you  are selecting the same element ('number'). If you are using Chrome, use the inspection tools (F12) to see wha is actually being rendered. JS will also fall through after the first error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given all your inputs the id of `number`, and when you are looking for an element of this ID, you will always find the first such element - so this is why the buttons are only working for the first input. A solution would be to give each input a different id, such as `number-1, number-2 etc`. Here is how I did this, notice I kept the for loop, because I don't know if you are using it for anything else.

Edit: Better explanation: Each button (add/subtract) has its own ID. For example, `add_btn_1`. When a button is clicked, we look at the number in its id, and use this number to construct a string which corresponds to the ID of the input we want to manipulate. For example `sub_btn_3` becomes `number-3`, which is the id of the 4th input field. Now we can change its value.

Here is the for-loop version, much like yours:

```js
const NumberContainer = document.getElementById("NumberContainer");

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    
    //Number Input Field
        var myParent3 = NumberContainer;
        var numberfield = document.createElement("input");
        numberfield.setAttribute('class','numberfield');
        numberfield.setAttribute('id','number-' + i);
        numberfield.setAttribute('value','0');      
        myParent3.appendChild(numberfield);
            
            
            
    //Buttons to add and subtract
        var myParent4 = SubtractContainer;
        var subtractButton = document.createElement("button");
        subtractButton.setAttribute('class','subtractButton');
        subtractButton.textContent = "-";
        subtractButton.id = "sub_btn_" + i;
        subtractButton.setAttribute('onclick','subtract(this)');
        myParent4.appendChild(subtractButton);


        var myParent5 = AddContainer;
        var addButton = document.createElement("button");
        addButton.setAttribute('class','addButton');
        addButton.id = "add_btn_" + i;
        addButton.textContent = "+";
        addButton.setAttribute('onclick','add(this)');
        myParent5.appendChild(addButton);   
};
    
    function add(btn){
        const num = btn.id.replace("add_btn_", "");
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number-' + num).value);
        value++;
        document.getElementById('number-' + num).value = value;
    };
    function subtract(btn){
        const num = btn.id.replace("sub_btn_", "");
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number-'+num).value);
        value--;
        document.getElementById('number-'+num).value = value;
};
```

```css
div { width: 100%; }
        input,button { width: 19%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div id="NumberContainer"></div>
<div id="SubtractContainer"></div>
<div id="AddContainer"></div>
```

Here are the lines I added:
In the creation logic:

- `subtractButton.id = "sub_btn_" + i;`
- `addButton.id = "add_btn_" + i;`
- `numberfield.setAttribute('id','number-' + i);`

Then in the event logic:

- `const num = btn.id.replace("add_btn_", "");` To get the number inside the clicked button's id
- `document.getElementById('number-'+num)` to get the input with the ID we want.

Comment: If you consider this the correct solution, would you mind accepting the answer (ie giving it a checkmark) so future generations/users will be able to find the answer if they have a similar problem?